# Track Directory or file changes when you run the code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a tool that go through certain path using os.walk to check the folder if it's empty or not and list down the folders and files inside it if there is any this is how the result is

### ...\1.This folder\My Folder\Recored

### ['My Text 1.txt', 'My Text 2.txt']

OR

### ...\1.My Pic

### This Folder is empty :(

what I want to do is track changes and color with red the new folders or the files that has been modified since the last run.

I don't want to keep watching the changes I want to see what has been change since the last run

I was trying to have something in text like log so I can compare between the current list and the text with no success

```
for path, directory, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\J\MyFolder'):
    if files or directory:
        print(path)
        print("\n")
        print((os.listdir(path)))
```

Comment: "I want to see what has been change since the last run" then you'll have to save results and compare them with the previous run. The OS or python library has no notion of "the last run", so you'll have to do that yourself or find a library that does such thing. What have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks for your reply and that correct you can't save the previous run thats why i was trying to save it in text but I couldn't find a way to compare between text and the current list that is generated from os.walk :(

Answer (score 0):

Folder modified timestamp (*os.path.getmtime("folder_path")*) will provide information about folder changes timestamp value.

Your system (tool which you have created) can tell when it ran previously and also get the timestamp of folder which you are scanning, compare and color it accordingly.

To get changes in datetime format;
*datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(folder_path))*

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't want to overwhelm the user with numbers I want if there is change the folder name to be in red EX: ['My Text 1.txt', 'My Text 2.txt'] if "My Text2.txt was modified it should appear in red  or if it's newly created !

Comment: okay but how can i compare!,  my issue is that I don't know how save the first run data and how to compare it with the next run thats my issue